# How to get (without vba) the last available data on a row in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a question regarding a simple formula: Gn=Fn-En, but if En is an empty cell, then search on the same row (n), all the n-1 values in order to find the first non empty cell.
Is it possible to make such formula but without having any vba code?

Regards,

Comment: A specific example would help here

Answer (score 1):

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B5:E5<>""),B5:E5)
```

will work for any single-row or single-column range

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last non-empty cell value in a row with hlookup.
For row 5, if values are numeric:
`=HLOOKUP(10^10,5:5,1,1)`
if values are text:
`=HLOOKUP(REPT("z",50),5:5,1,1)`
HTH